# Moving from one page to another using a child element of ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to move from one page to another by clicking on a child element of an ExpandableListView?  I'm new to android programming and one thing I found strange is that with child elements of ELV you can only write boolean methods, but a boolean doesn't work if you have to do an intent activity to move to another page?  I would think something like this would be straight forward and simple but I have yet to find a post where there is an answer yet I have seen this type of  set up in other apps.  Any rescue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on following URL for better understanding of click event implementation in ExpandableListView.
http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Intents work just fine with expandable list Views. I can show you how I did in my app. Hope it helps. :)

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
            int gp = (int) listAdapter.getGroupId(groupPosition);
            int cp = (int) listAdapter.getChildId(groupPosition,
                    childPosition);
            if (gp == 0) {
                switch (cp) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ExpandableLV.this,
                            com.example.rssfeed.customlistview.List1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            com.example.rssfeed.customlistview.List2.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                break;
                case 2:
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Toi.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Toi.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                    break;
                }
            } else if (gp == 1) {
                switch (cp) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            com.example.rssfeed.customlistview.List3.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent i3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            com.example.rssfeed.customlistview.List4.class);
                    startActivity(i3);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }
    });
```

I have 2 groups of expandable list views in this.